# Consulta mySQL mostrar un resultado de varios que estan duplicados

Tags: mysql

Buen dia,

acabo de hacer un autocomplete a un input mediante mySQL

el problema es que si tengo en una tabla clientes, los nombres

camilo
camilo
carlos

al oprimir "c" en el input me aparecen los tres resultados, es decir me toma los dos camilos normalmente

como podria hacer para que solo aparezcan las opciones

camilo
carlos

es decir ignorar que hay dos "camilo" y me muestre 1 solo, le puse LIMIT 1 pero aprendí que me muestra solo uno en este caso camilo ya que esta ordenado por orden ascendente

imagino eso debo parametrizarlo en la consulta mysql, actualmente la tengo asi, 
donde la variable

```
$_POST["query"]
```

es el termino de busqueda digitado en el input

```
SELECT * FROM cuentas WHERE nombre_cliente LIKE '%".$_POST["query"]."%' ORDER BY nombre_cliente ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Prueba usando dentro de tu sentencia SQL el parametro distinct que ayuda a eliminar de la lista de resultados los valores repetidos, así:

```
SELECT distinct valor1, valor2 FROM cuentas WHERE nombre_cliente LIKE '%".$_POST["query"]."%' ORDER BY nombre_cliente ASC;
```

Eso si en lugar de usar * pasale los nombres de las columnas que deseas te devuelva

Comment: Gracias!! justo lo que necesitaba... muy amable!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT column1 FROM table
```

Esto traerá devuelta los regustros únicos de el campo que quieras